# IOS - detecting the keyboard

Tags: ios

I was wondering how I can detect the keyboard in IOS when it is on screen. I am working on it all day but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

There is special `NSNotification` to handle that. You can add observer to listen for it (don't forget to unsubscribe)

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShown:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
```

And then you can handle that in the method:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShown:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // handle 
}
```